# Adding a space after each text in a HTML textArea

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website that transliterates English words typed to Hindi words.
However it does so if we actually type it out and press 'space' after each typed word.

I want to paste a paragraph and simulate a "spacebar" in javascript after each word in the text area so that it can be transliterated at once.

I tried adding space " " via javascript but it does not work. I need to simulate keyboard event space bar.

javascript solution is appreciated.

The website that does this is - http://indiatyping.com/index.php/english-to-hindi-typing

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert them to an array and then use a .split(" "); make sure you have a space between the "" and this will split the words and put spaces in between it. Give it a try =)

Comment: Already mentioned that in the question. I tried adding the space. Does not work. It works when I provide a space via keyboard.

Comment: @AmanMathur Are your words in an array yet? if so, try joining them all and split them?

Comment: I did. document.getElementById("data").value.split(" ") gives me the words in an array.